# Backbone Nested Collections

Tags: javascript, web-applications, backbone.js

i'm trying to populate a nested collection that's inside a model, and taht last model inside another collection.
The code is the following

```
App.Models.Bed = Backbone.Model.extend();

App.Collections.Beds = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: App.Models.Bed,
initialize: function(models, options){
    this.room = options.room;
}
});

App.Models.Room = Backbone.Model.extend();

App.Collections.Room = Backbone.Collection.extend({
url: 'rooms/',
initialize: function(){
    this.on('reset', this.getBeds, this);
},

getBeds: function(){
    this.each(function( room ){
        room.beds = new App.Collections.Beds([], { room: room});
        room.beds.url = 'rooms/' + room.id + '/beds';
        room.beds.fetch();
        console.log(room.beds.toJSON());
    });
}
});
```

Now, if I execute:

```
var rooms = new App.Collections.Room();
rooms.fetch();
rooms.toJSON();
```

It gives me back just the rooms populated, but no beds property on each bed.
The wired thing is that it makes the request to the server at /rooms/1/beds and I get back each bed.

Is it populating the beds collection?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your time mates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to pass in the `Room Model` to the `Room Collections`.

Comment: It happens with everyone :)